# projective camera: back-projecting a point on the image plane into 3-space

Tags: geometry

suppose I got a projective camera model. for this model I would like to back-project a ray through a point in the image plane. I know that the equation for this is the following:
$$
y(\lambda) = P^+_0 x_0 + \lambda c_0 
$$
where $P^+_0$
denotes the pseudoinverse of the camera matrix.
$x_0$ the point on the image plane and $c_0$ the center of the camera.

Now I don't fully get this equation. I get that $P^+_0 x_0$ results in a point on the line we are looking for. Hence we have two points that we can use for constructing a line. However I don't get the parametrization using $\lambda$. Why is the equation not in the form like:
$$y(\lambda) = (1-\lambda) a + \lambda b$$

Any help in understanding the original equation of the resulting ray would be appreciated! :D

Comment: It's from the book "Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision" page 162. Furthermore I encountered it in some papers.